# Where is __MWERKS__ in OS10.7?

Tags: c++, macos, photoshop

In Photoshop CS2 SDK file SPConfig.h, the follow code get error.Obviously I needed the define of **__*MWERKS*__**. The Compiler is LLVM GCC 4.2, the SDK is OS X 10.7 .

```
#ifdef __MWERKS__
#if !defined(__INTEL__) /* mjf was- #if defined(__MC68K__) || defined(__POWERPC__) */
#ifndef MAC_ENV
#define MAC_ENV 1
#endif
#endif
#endif

#if !defined(WIN_ENV) && !defined(MAC_ENV)
#error
#endif
```

In file cdefs.h:

```
#if defined(__MWERKS__) && (__MWERKS__ > 0x2400)
```

I want to know how to find where it defines. Or can I just define a number to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those macros are defined by the compiler itself to indicate which compiler it is (so you can write compiler-specific things).

`__MWERKS__` was used by Metrowerks CodeWarrior, which was discontinued in 2005, so is slightly obsolete by now.
You should not define it yourself - unless you're compiling with CodeWarrior, those parts *should* be skipped, or the program will most likely break in unpredictable ways.

Your actual problem is that your compiler & SDK combination isn't recognized as a Macintosh environment.

There must be some other place that defines `MAC_ENV`.
(I find it hard to believe that the CS2 SDK wouldn't support Apple's own compiler.)
You should go search for all occurrences of `MAC_ENV`.

Are you sure that the combination of SDKs and compiler you're using is supported?
The CS2 SDK is so old it might not be, so you should also read the documentation carefully.

Comment: Can I get the OSX(not the powerPC) version of Metrowerks CodeWarrior for free? I'm a student and can't afford the expense . Or how can I use X-code to develop a plugin of photoshop?

Comment: @user2918259 No, you can't get it for free anywhere. In fact, you can't even buy it - as I said, it was discontinued a long time ago.  Even if you could somehow get hold of it there's no chance of it supporting your machine since it was discontinued before the release of Intel Macs, and six years before 10.7. Have you tried to use XCode? It would be strange if it didn't work. The CS2 SDK should contain instructions for how to do it, but you may need to look for an old version of XCode on developer.apple.com